# Vue.js Konva library to display a simple image, what am I missing?

Tags: vue.js, konvajs

So I went through the sample code listed on the vue-konva page. Although it samples creating shapes I understood it enough to try to display a simple image to start. Here is the base code. My question lies in how do I attach the actual image file to the "image" property. Or if I am missing something else.

```
 <template>
  <div id="app">
    <h1>Display Image via Konva</h1>
    <div>
      <v-stage ref="stage" :config="configKonva">
        <v-layer ref="layer">
          <v-image :config="configImg"></v-image>
        </v-layer>
      </v-stage>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Vue from 'vue';
  import VueKonva from 'vue-konva'
  Vue.use(VueKonva)

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      testImg: new Image(),
      configKonva: {
        width: 500,
        height: 500
      },
      configImg: {
        x: 20,
        y: 20,
        image: this.testImg,
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
      },
    }
  }
</script>
```

According to the Konva Docs this is how to do it:

```
var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.onload = function() {
  var image = new Konva.Image({
    x: 200,
    y: 50,
    image: imageObj,
    width: 100,
    height: 100
  });
};
imageObj.src = '/path/to/image.jpg'
```

Therefore I believe the issue lies in how I attach the actual image file to the image property.

```
I tried the all following:

#1
image: "/path/to/image.jpg"
#2
mounted(){
   this.testImg.src = "/path/to/image.jpg"
}
#3
data(){
  return{
    testImg: "/path/to/image.jpg"
    }
  }
}
```

nothing seems to work. I'm sure there is a step I am missing.

Comment: By the way my image that i'm trying to display is in the "static" folder of my vue.js project. If that helps.

Comment: **Vue.js version 2.4+ is required** - is your Vue version correct?

Comment: I just checked and I'm running Vue.js v2.5.13

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trick seems to be to make `configImg` reactive by putting it in a computed property, since the image will load after mounting.

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      testImg: new Image(100, 100),
      configKonva: {
        width: 200,
        height: 200
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    configImg: function() {
      return {
        x: 20,
        y: 20,
        image: this.testImg,
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.testImg.src = "https://konvajs.github.io/assets/lion.png"
  }
}
```

Comment: That worked like a charm! I figured it had to do with attaching the image to the "image" property of the Konva Image, I just did not understand how to implement the procedure properly. Thank You!

Comment: This works great, but if I change the path to an image file in assets `../assets/image.png` it doesn't find it. When loading images in an `<img>` tag I had to do `require(path/to/img` but this also doesn't work here.

Comment: Have you tried putting your images in the "static" folder and reading them from there? I have no problems reading files from there.

Comment: Yes - this is the trick.  If you try to set the properties in the <v-whatever> tag, they don't seem to be reactive, but if you use :config and a computed property, they are.

Comment: Sorry but this is not working for me, `this.testImg.src` assigment needs to be in `created()` do display without using `draw()` in a callback.

Answer (score 1):

```
  mounted() {
    this.testImg.onload = () => this.$refs.layerImg.getStage().draw()
    this.testImg.src = "https://konvajs.github.io/assets/lion.png"
  }
```

Comment: Code is always good, but it also helps to add some comments/context around how this addresses the original question.

Comment: soryy i dont speack english