# Unable to load image from computer with vue into konva layer

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to put an image on a `vue-konva` layer using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48592101/2241241) solution. The solution works fine, when loading the image from the web, as in the example, but I cannot change it to work with a `png` I have in `assets`.

Based on my folder structure the source should be `'../assets/image.png'` But it doesn't find it, nor `~/assets/image.png` or `@assets/image.png` or `"require('../assets/image.png)"`.

(I used `vue-cli` to start a template project and am using the local dev thingy called by `npm run dev` to test. I am not sure if this has to do anything with the path issues, but I never used such a system before so it might as well as far as I know)

Comment: I put my images in the "static" folder.  (~/static). In the root of my project. I can read them fine from there. I also upload the "static" with the "dist" folder to my host.

Comment: For `'~/static/img/room_background.png'` I get `room_background.png:1 GET http://localhost:8002/~/static/img/room_background.png 404 (Not Found)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Credits: the solution is by matt_rothenberg#3118 on the Vue Land channel on discord).

Here is a sandbox for [it](https://codesandbox.io/s/q8qz9ll9lq)

And the code:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-stage ref="stage" :config="configKonva">
      <v-layer ref="layer">
        <v-image :config="configBackground"></v-image>
      </v-layer>
    </v-stage>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
const image = require("../assets/logo.png");

export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  data() {
    return {
      configKonva: {
        width: 200,
        height: 200
      },
      configBackground: {
        x: 20,
        y: 20,
        image: new Image(),
        width: 200,
        height: 200
      }
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.configBackground.image.src = image;
  }
};
</script>
```

The configBackground was moved to `data` instead of computed, and the image is loaded via `require`.