# How to use Sprite objects/animations in Vue Konva?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, konvajs

I'm trying to create a spritesheet animation in Vue with konva.js (utilizing [vue-konva](https://github.com/konvajs/vue-konva)).

In **pure konva.js**, the Sprite object is created [this way](https://konvajs.github.io/docs/shapes/Sprite.html) - in short, the  Image object is created at first, and then the Sprite object is created in the onload callback of Image object.

```js
var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.onload = function() {
  var blob = new Konva.Sprite({
    x: 50,
    y: 50,
    image: imageObj,
    animation: 'idle',
    animations: animations, // object defined earlier
    frameRate: 7,
    frameIndex: 0
  });

  // add the shape to the layer
  layer.add(blob);

  // add the layer to the stage
  stage.add(layer);

  // start sprite animation
  blob.start();
};
imageObj.src = '/assets/blob-sprite.png';
```

On the other hand, in **vue-konva** it is possible to create Konva objects as components directly in the `<template>` section of the `.vue` file, like this:

```html
<template>
  <v-stage :config="configKonva">
    <v-layer>
      <v-circle :config="configCircle"></v-circle>
    </v-layer>
  </v-stage>
</template>
```

**My questions are:**

1. is it possible to create `<v-sprite :config="configSprite"></v-sprite>` component? There are no mentions of this in the documentation.
2. If so, how should one correctly provide the necessary `image` attribute for the `configSprite` object?
3. How can one control the animations of `v-sprite` (starting/stopping)?
4. If all of this is not possible by using a `v-sprite` component, is it possible to somehow create the Sprite object manually and add it to the necessary `v-layer`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sprite component is very similar to `v-image` component. You can take a look into images demos: https://konvajs.github.io/docs/vue/Images.html

To start/pause sprite you have to access native `Konva` object and control animation manually. You can do this using references:

```
<template>
  <v-stage ref="stage" :config="stageSize">
    <v-layer ref="layer">
      <v-sprite
        @click="handleClick"
        ref="sprite"
        :config="{
          image: image,
          animation: 'idle',
          animations: animations,
          frameRate: 7,
          frameIndex: 0,
          animations: {
            idle: [
              2,
              2,
              70,
              119,
              71,
              2,
              74,
              119,
              146,
              2,
              81,
              119,
              226,
              2,
              76,
              119
            ],
            punch: [2, 138, 74, 122, 76, 138, 84, 122, 346, 138, 120, 122]
          }
        }"
      />
    </v-layer>
  </v-stage>
</template>

<script>
const width = window.innerWidth;
const height = window.innerHeight;

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      stageSize: {
        width: width,
        height: height
      },
      image: null
    };
  },
  created() {
    const image = new window.Image();
    image.src = "https://konvajs.github.io/assets/blob-sprite.png";
    image.onload = () => {
      // set image only when it is loaded
      this.image = image;
    };
  },
  methods: {
    handleClick() {
      const node = this.$refs.sprite.getNode();
      if (node.isRunning()) {
        node.stop();
      } else {
        node.start();
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Online demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/lxlqzok2m9

Comment: Thank you, this works! It should be noted, however, that the config for the sprite must either be **directly in the template** (as is the case in your example), or it has to be extracted **as a computed property** - [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48592101/3578534). When using the **data()** for the config, it doesn't work, as the image is loaded after mounting. [Example of what I mean (using data, not working)](https://codesandbox.io/s/mjl10o9mlx)

Comment: @Arx you demo is not correct. `this.image` doesn't exist and `image` is not defined in data (instead it is defined deeply under `configSprite`). So vue doesn't know it needs to update the component when you use `this.image = image`. Here is fixed version: https://codesandbox.io/s/llj376q6z9

Comment: Hmm - but in my example, `this.image` in fact exists - it is right under `configSprite` object, not nested inside it (please check the brackets again). [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/q884v4xl64) is the same example where I moved the `image` property higher so that it is clearer. Anyway, the approach in your example (setting `this.configSprite.image` directly) works, thank you for that!

Comment: That property is here. But later you use `this.image` in `configSprite`. What it refers to? I think vm instance don't have that property defined when `data` is called. And it will be not automatically redefined when you set `this.image = image`.